# Conditional expression in JSP with Struts2 tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I maintain an old application developed with Struts2.

I updated Struts2 library from 2.3.19 to 2.3.24.

I'm deploying to Tomcat 8 with jdk8.

In a JSP I have this conditions that works fine with old Struts2 library, jdk 7 and Tomcat 7)

```
<s:if test='%{current.getClass().name == "com.mycompany.myapp.MyCalss1"}'>
  <div>Class1</div>
</s:if>
<s:if test='%{current.getClass().name == "com.mycompany.myapp.MyCalss2"}'>
  <div>Class2</div>
</s:if>
```

Anything changed from struts 2.3.19 to 2.3.24? or jdk8, Tomcat 8?

When I add `<s:property value="%{ficheCourante}"></s:property>` to the JSP it shows `com.mycompany.myapp.MyCalss2@46e9d4ac`.

Comment: Class retrieval `current.getClass()` in jsp isn't allowed anymore due to security reasons. Create a method and compare there.

Comment: It's used on multiple pages in the application, any refactoring advice?

Comment: You can create some base action with this method and replace all in jsp.

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam Sometimes you need to read release notes, especially before updating to the new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class retrieval (i.e. `current.getClass()`) in JSP isn't allowed anymore due to [security reasons](http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-020.html). Create a method in your action class and do the comparison there. In JSP you can call it something like that.

```
<s:if test="compareCurrentClass('com.mycompany.myapp.MyCalss1')">
```

Or if you need to pass instance of `current` to compare method then:

```
<s:if test="compareCurrentClass(current, 'com.mycompany.myapp.MyCalss1')">
```

In that case declare `compareCurrentClass` in your action as:

```
public boolean compareCurrentClass(Object current, String name)
```

BTW currently latest S2 version is `2.3.28`.

Comment: It's used on multiple pages in the application, any refactoring advice? How to do it on BaseAction extended by all the actions?

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam Yes, you can define this method in your base action, then all you need to do is change your jsp-s.

Comment: How I get the object in the Base Action from the jsp?

Comment: current is a private field on the Action

Comment: the name of the field and type of object vary from an Action to another

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam Well, you can pass it to method, as an object, also `compareCurrentClass(current, 'com.mycompany.myapp.MyCalss1')`.